# Como usar async / await em requisição get usando vue+axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, async-await

Galera tenho o seguinte código e gostaria de saber como consigo implementar um try / catch com async / await executando a mesma função:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    skills: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080/wp-json/api/v1/skills')
      .then(response => {
        this.skills = response
      }).catch(err => (console.log(err)))
  }
})
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Olá wDrik, qual é a necessidade de usar `try/catch`? A promise já faz isso por tí. Que parte do código queres proteger contra um erro?

Comment: Mano é que eu estou usando owl.carousel para exibir os dados que estão retornando.. só que o as vezes o carousel carega antes dos items por completo e isso buga o layout.. já coloque um timeOut.. msm assim ñ resolveu.. pensei que um async await poderia ajudar! vlw!

Comment: Você provavelmente preenche o carousel com os dados do array `skills` certo? Tente colocar um `v-if="skills.length"` provavelmente já resolve este problema, sem necessidade de try catch ou timeout. Se quiser poste o código todo que tento mais tarde.

Comment: Blz, man já entendi a lógica.. então usar um try, catch com async/await deve ser para um caso mais expecifíco ? Vlw!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caso queira aplicar o `async` no código do `mounted` você pode faze-lo da seguinte forma:

```
...
async mounted() {
  try {
    let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/wp-json/api/v1/skills');
    this.skills = response;
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
...
```

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.
>
> **Exemplo Simples**
>
> ```
> function resolverDepoisDe2Segundos(x) {
>   return new Promise(resolve => {
>     setTimeout(() => {
>       resolve(x);
>     }, 2000);
>   });
> }
>
> async function adicionar1(x) {
>   var a = resolverDepoisDe2Segundos(20);
>   var b = resolverDepoisDe2Segundos(30);
>   return x + await a + await b;
> }
>
> adicionar1(10).then(v => {
>   console.log(v);  // exibe 60 depois de 2 segundos.
> });
>
> async function adicionar2(x) {
>   var a = await resolverDepoisDe2Segundos(20);
>   var b = await resolverDepoisDe2Segundos(30);
>   return x + a + b;
> }
>
> adicionar2(10).then(v => {
>   console.log(v);  // exibe 60 depois de 4 segundos.
> });
> ```